# Nested list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

input:`d=[['Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Conf', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - alaw', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - trim', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - sname', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - recog', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Results', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Literal', 'Afiles - amp', 'Afiles - errors', 'Afiles - mishit', 'Afiles - matches', 'Afiles - nomatch', 'Afiles - silence', 'Afiles - filename', 'Afiles - matchesAboveThreshold']]`
mycode-

```
for i in d:
    for j in i:
        k=j.replace("Afiles - ","",1)
        if((k.find(" - "))>0):
            s=k.replace("segments - ASegment - ","")
            print s
        else:
            k=j.replace("Afiles - ","",1)
            print k
```

using the above code i got the following String and append those string to a nested list:

```
seg
Conf
alaw
trim
sname
recog
Results
Literal
amp
errors
mishit
matches
nomatch
silence
filename
matchesAboveThreshold
```

And i want my output to be:

```
[['seg','Conf','alaw','trim','sname','recog','Results','Literal','amp','errors','mishit','matches','nomatch','silence','filename','matchesAboveThreshold']]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [`split(delimiter)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function:

```
d = [['Afiles - segments - ASegment - seg', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Conf', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - alaw', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - trim', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - sname', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - recog', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Results', 'Afiles - segments - ASegment - Literal', 'Afiles - amp', 'Afiles - errors', 'Afiles - mishit', 'Afiles - matches', 'Afiles - nomatch', 'Afiles - silence', 'Afiles - filename', 'Afiles - matchesAboveThreshold']]

result = []

for l in d:
    result.append([]) # include a new list
    for s in l:
        result[-1].append(s.split(" - ")[-1])

print result
```

**Output:**

```
[['seg', 'Conf', 'alaw', 'trim', 'sname', 'recog', 'Results', 'Literal', 'amp', 'errors', 'mishit', 'matches', 'nomatch', 'silence', 'filename', 'matchesAboveThreshold']]
```

**Notes:**

- Remember that the notation `some_list[-1]` is used to access to the last element of a sequence.
- This assumes that you have a **list of lists**, and it will also return a **list of lists**.
- This can also be written with *list comprehension*:

`result = [[s.split(' - ')[-1] for s in l] for l in d]`

Answer (score 0):

This gets what you want:

```
result = [[item.split('-')[-1].strip() for item in alist] for alist in d]
```

which is the same as:

```
result = []
for alist in d:
    sub_list = []
    for item in alist:
        sub_list.append(item.split('-')[-1].strip())
    result.append(sub_list)
```

We are appending the `sub_list` to the `result` since the output you are expecting is a list of lists.

Take a look at [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function for python. It will simplify your code.

You could alternatively modify your code as:

```
result = []
for i in d:
    sub_list = []
    for j in i:
        k=j.replace("Afiles - ","",1)
        if((k.find(" - "))>0):
            ans=k.replace("segments - ASegment - ","")
        else:
            ans=j.replace("Afiles - ","",1)
        sub_list.append(ans)
    result.append(sub_list)
```

to get the same output